# How to change the google search appearance like the title and description?

Tags: seo, metadata

I have recently changed my website file hosting to dreamhost server. But in google search the meta description and the meta title is not updated.

Does anyone know the reason?

This is the website - http://www.mudon-dubai.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all likelihood, Google has yet to recrawl your website.

Below is an easy guide to getting the robot to take another look at your site, among other things:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en